# Refused to load the image 'https://authorization.example.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

This is my index.html, I deployed my node.js app in heroku but it throws me the image error.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,width=device-width,minimum- 
     scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no"/>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' data:; default-src 'self' 
     https://ea-authorization.herokuapp.com/">
```

Comment: Added extra spacing.

Answer (score 0):

try this meta tag 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https:">`

replace 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' data:; default-src 'self' 
     https://ea-authorization.herokuapp.com/">`

For more information [Follow this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy)